# how to run an X based app on a remote server and display it on my local Cygwin/x?

Tags: linux

I used to know quite a bit about X, but this was years ago and I've become rusty. I've got a linux server in runlevel 3, I'd like to keep it at that runlevel, but I'd like to run some X programs (say, xclock for sake of argument) and have it display on my PC desktop which is running Cygwin/X. How to do this?

Comment: pretty stupid to downvote this. This was a valid issue that took me probably 45 minutes to figure out. My real target was running a Sitescope java app which requires an X server to display to, but for the sake of simplicity and universality, "xclock" suffices to pose the problem. I've now got a procedure to run X programs on a server that does not run X, and display them on my laptop running Windows and Cygwin, through a firewall that blocks the X protocol. To the person(s) who downvoted: can you say the same?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out.

1. Make sure Cygwin/X is installed and running on the PC. This can be tested by opening a local cygwin shell and running "xclock" or "telnet localhost 6000" to connect to the local X server. You'll need to download "telnet" and "xclock" from Cygwin if you don't already have them.
2. On the PC, download "xhost" from cygwin, and run "xhost +" to allow the remove server to be able to connect to the local X server
3. In my case, I can ssh from my local PC to the remove server, but unknown firewall(s) in between, prevent the remote machine from connecting to my local Cygwin port 6000, so I have to use ssh port forwarding
4. on the local PC, run "ssh [remote server ip] -R 6000:localhost:6000" to set up the tunnel.
5. sshd_config on the remote server may need "GatewayPorts yes" configured to allow port 6000 to be opened
6. So now you have port 6000 open on the PC, and port 6000 open on the remote server
7. in a cygwin shell (on the local system), run "echo $DISPLAY" to determine which display port the X server listens on. The response will be something like "localhost:0" and we are interested not in "localhost" but in the number that comes after.
8. on the remote server, run the X app as follows: "DISPLAY="localhost:0" [X app]" assuming X port 0. Note that the "localhost" here refers to the server, not the PC.